# Translation of "… desto eher zu …"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

How should we translate this sentence from a 1918 paper on a phenomenon of electricity in conductors?

> Der Schroteffekt gibt desto eher zu Störungen Anlass, je größer die Abklingzeit, je kleiner also die Dämpfung des Empfangkreises ist.

The latter part from *je onwards* is easy, but the composition of *desto eher zu* is somewhat difficult. Google Translate is showing:

> The shot noise effect is more likely to cause disruption …

The dictionary meanings of *desto* is "all the" and *eher* implies earlier/ sooner and it does not match Google Translate. The wordings *all the sooner* does not make much sense. How is the *desto eher* combination typically used?

Comment: The dots on umlauts are not optional! I corrected this for you. If you want to write German text you have to learn how to create umlauts on your keyboard. An allowed workaround (not a solution, just a workaround!) is to write an e after the vowel (ä=ae, ö=oe, ü=ue), but omitting the dots is an error!

Comment: You are right. Danke schön. I installed German in Word. Still self-teaching the language to myself.

Comment: If you want to stick to the US keyboard layout in MS-Windows, you can use the *US International* keyboard layout instead of "plain US". This makes `"` a dead key. Press it, then `a` to get *ä* etc. If you need the *"* character, you have to follow it with a space. `Right Alt+s` gives *ß* in that keyboard layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word-pair *»je - desto«* is in English *"the - the"*

> **Je** jünger Kinder sind, **desto** kleiner sind sie.
>   **The** jounger children are, **the** smaller they are.

and *»desto eher«* is *"the more likely"*:

> **Je** lauter die Party ist, **desto eher** rufen die Nachbarn die Polizei.
>   **The** louder the party is, **the more likely** the neighbors will call the police.

This was your sentence. Cause and effect are in reverse order here, so *»desto«* (the effect) comes before the two causes (*»je«* appears twice, once for each cause):

> Der Schroteffekt gibt **desto eher** zu Störungen Anlass, **je** größer die Abklingzeit, **je** kleiner also die Dämpfung des Empfangkreises ist.

English is just a foreign language to me, but I think »"the more likely"« is a usefull translation:

> The shot noise effect is **the more likely** to cause disruption, **the** greater the decay time is, i.e. **the** smaller the attenuation/damping of the reception circuit is.

---

The word *»zu«* has nothing to do with *»je - desto«*. It is part of the phrase:

> **zu** etwas Anlass geben = etwas verursachen
>   to give a cause **to** something = to cause something

Comment: Thanks. So desto eher is a phrase, this makes so much sense now.

Comment: @M.Farooq: no, the *je ... desto* combination is what is fixed here. *Eher* is just one of many possible comparatives (see my answer).